# How to use loops with Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, variables, tkinter

Ive been trying to get a loop to make a list of buttons on a Tkinter window but I don't know if it is possible or if my code is just incorrect

```
count = 1
    height = 300
    width = 600
    while count > 26:
        for i in range(1-26):
            square = Button(win, text='', height=1, width=2)
            square.place(x=width, y=height)
            height = height + 20
            width = width + 30
            count = count + 1
```

This is my code and I expected it to make the line but it made nothing

Comment: You don't need to have the buttons do anything when you press them? In any case your code snippet has an invalid indentation on its second line atm. Also have to assume you already made win an Tk() object...and have you remembered to call win.mainloop() after?

Comment: You have typo error `range(1-26)` should be `range(-26)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an simple example how you can place the buttons "in line" (you can customize it to your needs):

```py
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.title("Simple App with buttons")
win.geometry("800x300")


def place_buttons(win, x, y, how_much=10):
    for _ in range(how_much):
        square = Button(win, text="", height=1, width=2)
        square.place(x=x, y=y)
        x += 80


place_buttons(win, 10, 100)
win.mainloop()
```

Creates this application:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two loops. Nothing in the while loop will run as it only runs when count is greater than 26 but count is 1. The for loop is using the wrong syntax for range. Double check the syntax for range, and how to create buttons in tkinter

https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_range.asp
https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/create-buttons-in-tkinter/

Comment: It is the correct syntax (doesn't raise a `SyntaxError`) but it doesn't make sense to have `range(-25)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).